# Create a method for a cross table

Tags: sas

I have the following dataset

```
DATA lefttab; 
 INPUT orderId Amt Cat;
 Datalines;

 1 12 1
 2 14 2
 3 12 2
 5 15 1
 6 12 1
;

DATA righttab; 
 INPUT orderId Amt Member;
 Datalines;

 2 12 0
 3 11 1
 3 14 1
 5 15 1
 6 16 1
 ;
```

I now created a link table in which I create an inner join:

```
data link_table(keep = orderId Cat Member);
 merge lefttab (in=a) righttab (in=b);
  by orderId;
  if a and b;
 run;
```

This works fine and gives me an overview of the orderId, Cat and member. What I would like to do now however is to get an overview of the percentage of Member per category that have a 1 avalue. So I would like to have a cross table that shows me that 66% of category 2 is member and 100% of category 1 is member.

I tried this:

```
 proc freq data=link_table;
  table Member Cat;
 run;
```

But this does not give me the result that I want. Any thoughts on how I can get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort your data, and then do your `proc freq` by `cat`:

```
proc sort data = link_table;
    by cat;
run;

proc freq data = link_table noprint;
    by cat;
    tables member /
    out = link_table_cross;
run;
```

Then you can limit to observations where `member = 1` if you so desire.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid sorting, `proc tabulate` would do this for you.

```
 proc tabulate data=link_table;
   class cat member;
   tables member,cat*colpctn;
 run;
```

`colpctn` gives you the column percent (percent of records in that column that are in that cell).  If you want the orientation flipped (member as columns) then flip the order of table and use `rowpctn`.